# Diffeomorphism between twice punctured sphere and cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, diffeomorphism

I have to show that $S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\lvert x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\neq \pm 1\}$ and
$S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\lvert x^2+y^2=1, -1<z<1\}$ are diffeomorphic.
If there is a diffeomorphism $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ such that $f$ is bijective and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$ the surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ are called diffeomorphic.

I would probably be able to show that the function would be bijective and $C^{\infty}$, but how do I even find that function?

I know that the sphere (without North- and Southpole) can be parameterized by:
$$
\phi_n: \mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow S_1, \phi_n(x,y)=(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{-1+x^2+y^2}{1+x^2+y^2})
$$

How would I find the diffeomorphism $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$?

Edit: Changed $\phi_n(x,y,z)$ to $\phi_n(x,y)$, deleted a wrong parameterization for the cylinder.

Comment: Your parameterizations are incorrectly written: the twice punctured sphere $S_1$ is 2-dimensional; but then you incorrectly write its parameterization using a 3-dimensional parameter space $\phi_n : \mathbb R^3 \to S_1$ and using three independent variables $\phi_n(x,y,z)$. You do the same incorrect thing for $S_2$.

Comment: On top of that, your explicit parameterization and your implicit function descriptions do not match, neither for $S_1$ nor for $S_2$. For instance, from comparison of the implicit equation $x^2+y^2=1$ for $S_2$ and the explicit parameterization $\psi_n$ for $S_2$, I would have expected the explicit $x$ and $y$ coordinate functions in the formula for $\psi_n$ to satisfy the equation $$\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2} \right)^2 = 1$$ but that equation is clearly false.

Comment: @LeeMosher I changed it to $\phi_n(x,y)$, would that part be correct? What would be the correct parameterization for the cylinder? I assumed the x- and y-coordinate would be a circle and then added height as z-coordinate. Maybe I am having a brainlag on this part and it should be something like:
$$
\psi_n(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z},z)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maps
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
F_1\colon & S_1 & \longrightarrow & S_2 \\
& (x,y,z) & \longmapsto & \displaystyle\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},z\right)
\end{array}$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
F_2\colon & S_2 & \longrightarrow & S_1 \\
& (x,y,z) & \longmapsto & \displaystyle\left(\sqrt{1-z^2}x,\sqrt{1-z^2}y,z\right)
\end{array}
$$
are smooth (as restriction of smooth maps on an open set of $\Bbb R^3$) and are inverse of each other.

Here is how I found these functions.
Fixing $z=c$ gives an horizontal slice for $S_1$ and $S_2$, and it turns out (this is clear if you draw a picture) that $S_1\cap \{z=c\}$
is a circle of radius $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{1-c^2}$, while $S_2\cap\{z=c\}$ is a circle of radius $1$.
You just have to find the right dilation between these two circles.

Comment: Much appreciated! I think I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You can't because they're not diffeomorphic by comparing their fundamental groups for example. A sphere minus two points, however, is diffeomorphic to a cylinder essentially for the same real the plane minus a point is diffeomorphic to a plane minus a closed disk.

Comment: In the question, the two poles of the sphere are removed, making it diffeomorphic to a cylinder. The title is confusing

Comment: It looks like OP edited the title of the question to match the body after I answered.

Comment: Yes, they did (after my comment, actually!)

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was confusing, I thought the body would be enough.